# Regex to get anything after last space in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that has a bunch of words in it and all I want is the last word. What would be the Regex for this?

For example:

```
This is some sample words to work with
```

I would just want `with` from the above string.

Comment: Does it _have_ to be a regex? `input.Split(' ').Last()` will do.. Also, please share what you have tried.

Comment: Why you want to use `Regex` here?

Comment: @Sybren - I know how to do it the other ways. Just trying to use/learn something new. Why not use `Regex`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for :

```
[\d-]+$
```

demo here: https://regex101.com/r/hL9aR8/2

Comment: At first I did not thing that this would make a difference with my inexperience in Regex, but now I see how this could be an issue. So the string has numbers in it, and those are actually what I want to get. The string actually looks like this: `here is some text 31` or `here is some more text 29-31` I always want to get the numbers. so either `31` or `29-31`. Sorry for the inconvenience. Would you be able to help with this?

Comment: I think we have a winner. Thank you!

Comment: That information would have been helpful in avoiding the "this is not appropriate for regex" comments :)

Answer (score 5):

A far easier solution would be to do it with the `Split` method:

```
string text = "This is some sample text to work with";
string last = text.Split(' ').Last();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `LastIndexOf`, should perform better.

```
string text = "This is some sample words to work with";
string last = text.Substring(text.LastIndexOf(' '));
```

Of course if there's a chance that the text won't have any whitespace, you would have to make sure you are not trying to substring from -1 index.

Comment: I am not trying to be argumentative, I am just wondering why one would preform better over another? I know how to do this the other ways, but in my question I asked with `Regex`...

Comment: Regex is capable of really complicated things, but it usually doesn't perform as good as code written especially for a scenario. Since this case is super simple to do without regex - you would be better off without it here. When you need to make sure a string is an email (or any other complicated validations) regex is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Altough a bit late for your need I guess, but this should work:

Replace "[a-zA-Z]+$" with "[\S]+$" => will take all characters that are not spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using regex, then following will help you

```
/[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dB5tB7/1)

**Example**

```
Match m = Regex.Matches("This is some sample words to work with", "[a-zA-Z]+$")[0];
Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
=> with
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would you happen to know the more appropriate way of using this in C#?

Comment: At first I did not thing that this would make a difference with my inexperience in Regex, but now I see how this could be an issue. So the string has numbers in it, and those are actually what I want to get. The string actually looks like this: `here is some text 31` or `here is some more text 29-31` I always want to get the numbers. so either `31` or `29-31`. Sorry for the inconvenience. Would you be able to help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Per original question (without the numbers at the end) to get "with":

```
[^\W]+$

Regex.Match("This is some sample words to work with", @"[^\W]+$").Value == "with"
```